# latex float caption first letter capital, rest lower case

Tags: latex, caption

I am trying to force the first letter of a caption ot be uppercase, and the rest lower case.
There seems to be a clash between xstring and subfig (that I need)

```
\documentclass{article}                     
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xstring}
% Redefine \caption command to capitalize the first letter
\let\oldcaption\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{%
\StrLeft{#1}{1}[\firstletter]%
\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{1}[\therest]%
\oldcaption{\MakeUppercase\firstletter\MakeLowercase{\therest}}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\caption{this Is A saMple a sample caption.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look at https://ctan.org/pkg/mfirstuc

Comment: Can not work, as the next block will force everything to be lowercase

Comment: Are you sure forcing lowercase is a good idea? I can kind of understand why the first letter should be upper case, but captions can contain all kinds of stuff which should be uppercase: The names of persons, acronyms, cross-references, variables ....

Comment: two reasons, most publications demand lower case; 2) in a large document written over the years captions have been written as lower case, upper case, sentence case. This will ensure uniformity